# Dart Object Comparison. Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, object

I am trying to compare objects, but the case is that although I have the following:

```
Person p = Person("nombre", "Apellido");
Person p2 = Person("nombre", "Apellido");
if(p == p2){
 print("IGUALES");
}else{
 print("DIFERENTES");
}
```

It keeps telling me that they are not the same when they are not, and I do not know why it happens or if the comparator "==" does not work when comparing objects. I have also tried but there is no way.

```
if(identical(p, p2)){
 print("IGUALES");
}else{
 print("DIFERENTES");
}
```

Comment: can you include the `Person` class

Comment: They already solved it for me below but thank you very much anyway;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because by default the `==` operator checks if the object is the **same** object by checking it's reference in memory. If you want a value based equality you should either override the `==` operator and hashCode (which is difficult to do by hand) or you could use [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) (a well known and maintained package for value based equality).

```
class Person extends Equatable {
  final String nombre;
  final String apellido;
  ...
  ...
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [nombre, apellido];

}
```