# Dart Comparison of Objects within a list

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

You will see I am trying that when I pass him three objects, he only stays with the objects that do not repeat themselves, that is, regarding the following:

```
Person p = Person("nombre", "apellido");
Person p2 = Person("nombre", "apellido");
Person p3 = Person("nombre2", "apellido2");

var list = [ p, p2, p3 ];
Set<Persona> set2 = {...list};

var i = 1;
filteredList.forEach((element) {
 print("Person " + i.toString() + ": " + element.toString());
 i++;
});
```

It should return something like this:

```
Person 1: Person{nombre: nombre, apellido: apellido}
Person 3: Person{nombre: nombre2, apellido: apellido2}
```

The Person class for now is like this:

```
Person 1: Person{nombre: nombre, apellido: apellido}
Person 2: Person{nombre: nombre, apellido: apellido}
Person 3: Person{nombre: nombre2, apellido: apellido2}
```

La clase Persona por aora esta tal que asi:

```
class Person {
  String nombre;
  String apellido;

  Person(this.nombre, this.apellido);

  @override
  bool operator ==(other) {
    return (other is Person)
        && other.nombre == nombre
        && other.apellido == apellido;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Person{nombre: $nombre, apellido: $apellido}';
  }
}
```

Comment: you need `Person.hashCode` property implemented too (for example by using `hashValues` top level function or `Object.hashAll` method)

Comment: As explained by [the answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69662158/), you must override *both* `operator ==` *and* `hashCode`.  A `Set` depends on both to identify objects that should be considered unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two objects that should be equal are not getting detected by the set implementation, so what's going on here?

The `Set` documentation gives us our first clue:

> The default `Set` implementation, `LinkedHashSet`, considers objects indistinguishable if they are equal with regard to operator `Object.==`.

`==` is implemented correctly here, though. Lets see what `LinkedHashSet` has to say about equality:

> The elements of a LinkedHashSet must have consistent Object.== and Object.hashCode implementations. This means that the == operator must define a stable equivalence relation on the elements (reflexive, symmetric, transitive, and consistent over time), and that hashCode must be the same for objects that are considered equal by ==.

While `==` is implemented in your class, `hashCode` is not. This is an issue, because as we can see, the default `Set` implementation relies on it.

Luckily, Dart 2.14 makes your job quite easy:

```dart
int get hashCode => Object.hash(nombre, apellidio);
```